# adding a number to scatterplot location based on list value

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colors, label

I am having the following problem. The plot below represents an area. The colors are assigned based on the period they belong to. Since I have around 22 periods and sometimes even more it is on most color scales sometimes hard to see the difference between different periods. Therefore I would like to add small numbers in the middle of each square. The number should be the same as the PeriodNumbersGood number for that position.

I hope anyone can help me out and or has any tips for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
PeriodNumbersGood = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22]

XGOOD = [336350.0, 336450.0, 336450.0, 336550.0, 336650.0, 336750.0, 336650.0, 336650.0, 336550.0, 336550.0, 336650.0, 336650.0, 336750.0, 336850.0, 336850.0, 336750.0, 336750.0, 336850.0, 336950.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 336950.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 336850.0, 336850.0, 336950.0, 336850.0, 336750.0, 336750.0, 336650.0, 336750.0, 336850.0, 336950.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 336850.0, 336850.0, 336950.0, 337050.0, 337150.0, 337150.0, 337050.0, 337050.0, 337150.0, 337150.0, 337250.0, 337250.0, 337250.0, 337350.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337250.0, 337350.0, 337250.0, 337150.0, 337050.0, 337150.0, 337050.0, 337150.0, 337250.0, 337350.0, 337250.0, 337250.0, 337150.0, 337150.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 337150.0, 337050.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 337150.0, 337450.0, 337450.0, 337450.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337450.0, 337450.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337250.0, 337350.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337250.0, 337250.0, 337150.0, 337250.0, 337250.0, 337250.0, 337150.0, 337150.0, 337050.0, 336950.0, 337150.0, 337250.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337550.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337250.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337750.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337750.0, 337750.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 338050.0, 338050.0, 337950.0, 338050.0, 338150.0, 338250.0, 338150.0, 338150.0, 338250.0, 338150.0, 338050.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 337850.0, 337950.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337450.0, 337450.0, 337350.0, 337350.0, 337450.0, 337550.0, 337450.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 338050.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337650.0, 337550.0, 337550.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337650.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 337950.0, 338050.0, 338150.0, 338150.0, 338050.0, 338050.0, 337950.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337850.0, 337750.0, 337950.0, 338050.0, 338050.0, 338150.0, 338150.0, 338250.0, 338350.0, 338350.0, 338250.0, 338350.0, 338350.0, 338250.0, 338050.0, 338050.0, 338150.0, 338050.0, 338050.0, 338150.0, 338250.0, 338250.0, 337850.0, 337950.0, 337850.0, 336550.0]
YGOOD = [7089650.0, 7089550.0, 7089650.0, 7089550.0, 7089450.0, 7089350.0, 7089350.0, 7089250.0, 7089350.0, 7089450.0, 7089550.0, 7089650.0, 7089550.0, 7089450.0, 7089350.0, 7089450.0, 7089250.0, 7089250.0, 7089250.0, 7089350.0, 7089450.0, 7089350.0, 7089250.0, 7089150.0, 7089150.0, 7089050.0, 7088950.0, 7088950.0, 7089050.0, 7089150.0, 7089150.0, 7088950.0, 7088850.0, 7088750.0, 7088650.0, 7088650.0, 7088650.0, 7088750.0, 7088850.0, 7088950.0, 7088850.0, 7088950.0, 7089050.0, 7089150.0, 7089050.0, 7089150.0, 7089050.0, 7088950.0, 7088850.0, 7088850.0, 7088750.0, 7088650.0, 7088650.0, 7088550.0, 7088450.0, 7088350.0, 7088450.0, 7088350.0, 7088250.0, 7088250.0, 7088350.0, 7088450.0, 7088550.0, 7088650.0, 7088750.0, 7088650.0, 7088550.0, 7088550.0, 7088450.0, 7088450.0, 7088550.0, 7088750.0, 7088850.0, 7088750.0, 7089050.0, 7089250.0, 7088750.0, 7088550.0, 7088450.0, 7088550.0, 7088450.0, 7088350.0, 7088250.0, 7088350.0, 7088250.0, 7088150.0, 7088050.0, 7088050.0, 7087950.0, 7087850.0, 7087750.0, 7087850.0, 7087950.0, 7088050.0, 7088150.0, 7088250.0, 7088350.0, 7088250.0, 7088150.0, 7088050.0, 7087950.0, 7087950.0, 7087850.0, 7087850.0, 7087750.0, 7087750.0, 7087850.0, 7087750.0, 7087850.0, 7087950.0, 7088050.0, 7088150.0, 7088050.0, 7088150.0, 7088150.0, 7088350.0, 7087950.0, 7087650.0, 7087550.0, 7087450.0, 7087550.0, 7087550.0, 7087450.0, 7087550.0, 7087650.0, 7087650.0, 7087650.0, 7087550.0, 7087650.0, 7087750.0, 7087750.0, 7087650.0, 7087750.0, 7087850.0, 7087850.0, 7087950.0, 7087950.0, 7088150.0, 7088250.0, 7088050.0, 7088150.0, 7087550.0, 7087450.0, 7087550.0, 7087450.0, 7087350.0, 7087250.0, 7087150.0, 7087050.0, 7086950.0, 7086950.0, 7086850.0, 7086750.0, 7086650.0, 7086750.0, 7086650.0, 7086550.0, 7086450.0, 7086450.0, 7086350.0, 7086250.0, 7086150.0, 7086150.0, 7086050.0, 7086150.0, 7086250.0, 7086250.0, 7086350.0, 7086350.0, 7086350.0, 7086450.0, 7086450.0, 7086550.0, 7086650.0, 7086750.0, 7086750.0, 7086850.0, 7086850.0, 7086750.0, 7086850.0, 7086950.0, 7086950.0, 7087050.0, 7087050.0, 7087050.0, 7087150.0, 7087150.0, 7087050.0, 7087050.0, 7087150.0, 7087250.0, 7087350.0, 7087350.0, 7087250.0, 7087150.0, 7087250.0, 7087350.0, 7087350.0, 7087450.0, 7087450.0, 7087350.0, 7087250.0, 7087350.0, 7087250.0, 7087150.0, 7087150.0, 7087050.0, 7086950.0, 7086950.0, 7086850.0, 7086850.0, 7086750.0, 7086650.0, 7086650.0, 7086550.0, 7086550.0, 7086650.0, 7086750.0, 7086650.0, 7086550.0, 7086450.0, 7086550.0, 7086650.0, 7086150.0, 7086050.0, 7085950.0, 7085850.0, 7085950.0, 7086050.0, 7086050.0, 7086150.0, 7086050.0, 7085950.0, 7085850.0, 7085750.0, 7085850.0, 7085850.0, 7085750.0, 7085650.0, 7085550.0, 7085450.0, 7085950.0, 7086250.0, 7086150.0, 7086250.0, 7086350.0, 7086450.0, 7086450.0, 7086350.0, 7086250.0, 7086350.0, 7086450.0, 7086550.0, 7086550.0, 7086750.0, 7086850.0, 7086950.0, 7086550.0, 7086350.0, 7086250.0, 7086250.0, 7086150.0, 7087250.0, 7087450.0, 7087650.0, 7089650.0]

plt.figure()
az = plt.subplot(111,aspect='equal')
az.scatter(XGOOD,YGOOD,c=PeriodNumbersGood, marker='s',s=160, lw=0, cmap= 'Dark2')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) to add label for each cell:

```
...
for i, label in enumerate(PeriodNumbersGood):
    az.annotate(label, (XGOOD[i]-35,YGOOD[i]-20))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , this is exactly what I was looking for.